# Slim Framework 3 Upload

Tags: php, upload, slim

I have problem upload files through slim framework 3 Slim\Http\UploadedFile.

My code:

```
$app->post('/upload', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    $setting = $this->settings;
    $uploadPath = $setting['upload']['path'];
    $file = $req->getUploadedFiles()['img'];
    $file->moveTo($uploadPath);
    return $res;
});
```

Result:

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: RuntimeException
Message: Error moving uploaded file hss.png to /home/xxx/web/slim3/app/../log
File: /home/xxx/web/slim3/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Http/UploadedFile.php
Line: 237
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already found out the answer. Thanks to @akrabat

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Slim 3</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yegor256.github.io/tacit/tacit.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Upload a file</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Select file to upload:</label>
            <input type="file" name="newfile">
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
$app->post('/upload', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    if (empty($files['newfile'])) {
        throw new Exception('Expected a newfile');
    }

    $newfile = $files['newfile'];
    // do something with $newfile
});
```

Comment: I've implemented exactly the same but i still can't upload a file via postman. always throws the key missing exception

Answer (score 0):

use this php [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) instead moveTo function

Answer (score 0):

```
//localhost store image
```

define('pic_root',"/var/www/html/api/app/photo");
 define('pic_image',"http://localhost/api/app/photo");

$app->post('/adduser', function($request,$response){

```
$post = $request->getParsedBody();

extract($post);

require 'db_connect.php';

$img =" ";
if($_FILES['photo']['error'] === 0){
    $files = $_FILES['photo'];
    $imgname = $files['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'], pic_image.'/'.$imgname);
    $img = pic_root.'/'.$imgname;
}

$q = "INSERT INTO users (name,phone,taluka,disticts,city,photo)
     VALUES ('".$name."','".$phone."','".$taluka."','".$disticts."','".$city."','".$img."')";

$user = $pdo->query($q);

$user = array(
                "status" => (bool)$user,
                "message" => "User Created"
            );
    return $response->withStatus(200)
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        ->write(json_encode($user,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

});

Comment: Can you add one or two lines, saying in how far this code solves the problem or in how far it differs from the code in the question? For correct code indendation you can use Ctrl+k.